# Finding the flow of a pushforward of vector field

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, derivatives

> 1. Let $\mathbb{X}$ be the vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by  $$ \mathbb{X}(x,y) = (y,x). $$ Compute the flow $\Phi_t$ of
>      $\mathbb{X}$.
> 2. Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the diffeomorphism given by $$ F(x,y) = (y + \sin x, x) $$ Find $F^{-1}$ and compute
>      $(F,\mathbb{X})(u,v)$.
> 3. Let $(u(t),v(t))$ denote the solution of the system of differential equations $$ \dot{u} = \cos v(u-\sin v) + v, \quad \dot{v} = u - \sin
>     v. $$ Find an explicit formula for the set of initial conditions
>      $(u_0,v_0)$ for which $(u(t),v(t)) \to (0,0)$ as $t \to \infty$.

$(1)$ I get that $\displaystyle \Phi_t(x,y)=\left(\frac{x+y}{2}e^t + \frac{y-x}{2}e^{-t}, \frac{x+y}{2}e^t + \frac{x-y}{2}e^{-t} \right)$

$(2)$ I get that $F^{-1}(x,y)=(y,x - \sin y)$ and $F_*X(x,y)=(\cos y (x-\sin y)+y , x -\sin y )$

$(3)$ This is the bit I am stuck on. I cannot see how to use part ii) which strongly resembles the system of differential equations to solve part iii). I think somehow you have to use that

[image]

I dont think this question should be as difficult as I am finding it. I believe that I am just missing one step. I dont think there needs to be much working done on your behalf.

UPDATE:

$$\begin{align}
&\Psi_t(x,y)\\ 
&= \left(F \circ \Phi_t \circ F^{-1})(x,y)\right) \\
&= \left(F  (\Phi_t(y, \sin x -y)\right) \\
&= F\left(\frac{y+(x-\sin y)}{2}e^t + \frac{(y-\sin x)-y}{2}e^{-t}, \frac{y+(y-\sin x)}{2}e^t + \frac{y-(y-\sin x)}{2}e^{-t} \right) \\
&= \left(\frac{y+(y-\sin x)}{2}e^t + \frac{y-(y-\sin x)}{2}e^{-t} )+\sin\left(\frac{y+(x-\sin y)}{2}e^t + \frac{(y-\sin x)-y}{2}e^{-t}\right), \frac{y+(x-\sin y)}{2}e^t + \frac{(y-\sin x)-y}{2}e^{-t} \right)
\end{align}$$

Surely this mess cannot be correct???

Comment: The vector field $(\dot u,\dot v)$ given in (3) is exactly the vector field $F_*X$ computed in (2). Let's denote the flow corresponding to $(\dot u,\dot v)$ by $\Psi_t.$ Moreover, from (1), we have the flow $\Phi_t$ corresponding to $X$, and from (2), we have $F^{-1}.$ From all this and proposition 1.7.3 we can compute $\Psi_t = F\circ \Phi_t \circ F^{-1}.$ Now that we have an explicit expression for $\Psi_t,$ we can use it to answer the question in (3).

Comment: @jflipp See my new update

Comment: Also could someone please edit this to make the brackets larger in the update. \bigg doesnt seem to work here. Moreover I cannot align these equations nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I calculated the same answer as you:

$$\Psi_t(x,y)=\left(\frac{y+x-\sin y}{2}e^t-\frac{\sin x}{2}e^{-t},\frac{y+x-\sin y}{2}e^t-\frac{\sin x}{2}e^{-t}\right)$$

The final answer is not that messy if you do some factoring

$$\Psi_t(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}\left(e^{2t}(y+x\sin y)-\sin x,e^{2t}(y+x-\sin y)-\sin x\right)$$

---

**Correction**:

We have $F(x,y)=(y+\sin x,x)$

$\Phi_t(x,y)=\left(\frac{x+y}{2}e^t+\frac{y-x}{2}e^{-t},\frac{x+y}{2}e^t+\frac{x-y}{2}e^{-t}\right)$

$F^{-1}(x,y)=(y,x - \sin y)$

$\Psi_t(x,y)=F\circ\Phi_t\circ F^{-1}(x,y)$

**Computation**:

$\Psi_t(x,y)=F(\Phi(y,x-\sin y))=F(\frac{x+y-\sin y}{2}e^t+\frac{x-y-\sin y}{2}e^{-t},\frac{x+y-\sin y}{2}e^t+\frac{y-x+\sin y}{2}e^{-t})$

$\Psi_t(x,y)=(\frac{x+y-\sin y}{2}e^t+\frac{y-x+\sin y}{2}e^{-t}+\sin(\frac{x+y-\sin y}{2}e^t+\frac{x-y-\sin y}{2}e^{-t}),\frac{x+y-\sin y}{2}e^t+\frac{x-y-\sin y}{2}e^{-t})$

Sorry, must have made a mistake, guess it is a messy answer.

Comment: Know anything about pullbacks? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083354/understanding-the-definition-of-a-pullback-of-a-differential-k-form-and-applyi

Comment: Ill have a look

Comment: Your solution doesnt go to $(0,0)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: How have you got $(\frac{y+(y-\sin x)}{2}e^t + \frac{y-(y-\sin x)}{2}e^{-t} )+\sin\left(\frac{y+(x-\sin y)}{2}e^t + \frac{(y-\sin x)-y}{2}e^{-t}\right) \mapsto \frac{y+x-\sin y}{2}e^t-\frac{\sin x}{2}e^{-t}$ ? in the 1st coordinate

Comment: You are correct about when $t\rightarrow\infty$, but surely this is still the flow of $\mathbb{Y}$. I can't see where you are referencing by "in the 1st coordinate.". Cant see that I wrote that anywhere.

Comment: You say I calculated the same answer as you, but its seem to be different to mine in the first coordinate, and I cannot see how you simplified it.

Comment: Sorry, but either I can't see what I did to get the answer before or I previously made a mistake, but in the edit I have my messy answer for the flow. See **edit** to my answer.