# Understanding the definition of a pullback of a differential $k$-form and applying it in $1-d$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, differential-forms

I am having trouble understanding the definition of a pullback of a differential k-form in a basic course in differentiable geometry.

[image]

This is the definition I am given. I believe it is easier to use what I hope is an equivalent identity of

$$ (F^*\beta)(x;u_{(1)},\dots,u_{(n)})=\beta(F(x); \ dF(x)u_{(1)},\dots,dF(x)u_{(n)}) $$

I believe that the definition of algebraic k-form is not widely used so here it is below.

[image]

Now in the following example you are asked to apply this definition of a pullback in 1-d.

[image]

[image]

I am struggling to understand how $\beta(F(x); F'(x)e_{(i)})=\beta_j(F(x))(F'(x)e_{(i)})^j$. (I believe there was a typo there.

I get that

$\begin{align} \alpha(x;e_{(i)}) &= F^*\beta(x;e_{(i)}) \\
&= \beta(F(x);dF(x)e_{(i)})
\end{align}$

Now as $\beta(y)=\beta_j(y)dy^j$ we could either do $y=F(x)$ and then get $\beta_j(F(x))d(F(x))^j$ which would be only half right. Not sure why this doesnt work.

or

$\begin{align} \beta(F(x);dF(x)e_{(i)}) &= (\beta_j(F(x))dy^j)(dF(x)e_{(i)}) \\
&= (\beta_j(F(x))dy^j)(dF(x)e_{(i)}) \\
&= (\beta_j(F(x))d(y^j(dF(x)e_{(i)}) \\
&= (\beta_j(F(x))d(dF(x)e_{(i)}))^j
\end{align}$

Again this is wrong but I am not sure how or why.

Also is $\displaystyle \alpha=F^*\beta=\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}\beta_j \circ F dx^i$ equivalent to $\displaystyle \alpha=F^*\beta= \beta_j \circ F \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i} dx^i$

Please keep answers simple as this is only a basic course. I am not familiar with tensors or tangent-anything.

Comment: Do you want a specific answer for this, or a general explanation? Also, why are you working with forms when you don't know tangent vectors? That's almost like talking to someone while avoiding eye contact: you're missing the big picture, and your knowledge will consequentially be less effective.

Comment: I think a specific answer would be best. Sometimes youre not sure though what you want until youve got something. Its my course that doesnt introduce tangent vectors, so I didnt learn them.

Comment: Would you mind if I did use them? They're really not difficult.

Comment: If as simple as possible and clearly explained with references to online sources if necessary. Id rather not do too much extra learning though but at the same time need to understand this much better than I do currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you seem to use the same book for a lot of your questions, I think the modern/standard approach with tangent vectors will probably just serve to confuse, even though it is easier.

The important point is simply that $\beta$ is a linear form. Assuming I'm understanding your notation correctly, $\beta_{j}(F(x))=\beta(F(x);e_{(j)})$, so $\sum_{j}\beta_j(F(x))(F'(x)e_{(i)})^j=\beta(F(x);F'(x)e_{(i)})$.

Think of $\beta(F(x))$ as a row vector, and $F'(x)e_{(i)}$ as a column vector. Then, this is the same as saying $$\begin{bmatrix}\beta_1(F(x)) & \cdots & \beta_n(F(x))\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(F'(x)e_{(i)})^1 \\ \vdots \\ (F'(x)e_{(i)})^n\end{bmatrix}=\beta(F(x);F'(x)e_{(i)}),$$ which is essential true by the definition you gave.

As to your equivalency question, I don't see why multiplication in the reals shouldn't commute. Do you?

Comment: I understand what you have said here but I am still struggling to understand how the $dy^j$ are evaluated. This is particularly wrt to cases where I am half right, see my question. Ideally I would like to understand where I am right and wrong in my thinking.

Comment: @1234 -- Unfortunately, I don't know how it works in something as convoluted as a differential geometry course without tangent vectors. If you look on the math.SE blog, I have a piece in there answering basic questions similar to this, so you might want to check it out.

Comment: I would hazard to guess, though, that the evaluation is the same as matrix multiplication. This appears to be consistent with what I was thinking when I was awake, post-coffee. I'll look at this in an hour or so and see if I'm being reasonable.

Comment: It appears that I was correct. To evaluate, say $\mathrm{d}y^j$, we apply it to whatever vector-thing $v$ your course works with by simply doing the dot product. That is, assuming $\mathrm{d}y^j$ has $j^\text{th}$ component $1$ and all other components $0$, $\mathrm{d}y^j(v)=v^j$.

Comment: This is the thing I dont get. Let us call $\beta(y)=\beta(y)dy^j$. We have $\beta_j(F(x))$ where $y=F(x)$. but for the $dy^j$ we dont evaluate $d(F(x))^j$, we evaluate something else.

Comment: @1234 -- Suppose $v=\sum_iv^ie_i$, where $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of a vector space $V$. For a linear endomorphism $T:V\to V$, $T(v)=\sum_it^ie_i$ for some $\{t^i\}$. Now, replace $e_i$ with $\mathrm{d}y^i$ in the above description. Make sense now?

Comment: I think that problem is the same here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080043/show-that-textbfs-textbfbu-v-textbfb-textbfsu-v-cdot-textb. I have put a lot of explanation to my thinking there. If you wouldnt mind having a look at it.

Comment: Cancel that. Ball has just dropped.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on it:
We start with a linear map between vector spaces, to set up the context. 
The pullback of a differential k-form $\theta $, associated to a differentiable mapping $f$ living in the space of $k-$forms  is equivalent to the dual of a multi-linear map between vector spaces $V,W$. The linear map that will be used is the differential $df$

Let

$V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces, and let $L: V \rightarrow W $ be a linear map (this generalizes to multilinear map). Then the dual map $L^{*}: W^{*} \rightarrow V^{*} $ (notice the "contravariance" of the associated map $L^{*}$) defined by $L^{*}(t)(v_1):= t(L(v_1)); t \in W^{*}$ Basically, we can turn an element in the dual of $W$ into an element on the dual of $V$ using this formula. Now, apply this idea with a map $f: M \rightarrow N$ , both manifolds $V,W$ are now the tangent spaces $T_pM, T_{f(p)}M $  and the linear map $L$ is the differential/pushforward map $df $. Then, given a linear map $L: T_p N \rightarrow  \mathbb R$, i.e., an element of the dual , i.e., a k-form on $T_pN$, you get a k-form defined on $T_pM$ as above